# Количество согласных звуков

Tags: фонетика

Доброго времени суток! Прошу подсказать мне количество согласных звуков в русском языке. Раньше всегда думала, что 36, но недавно нашла информацию, что 37. Теперь не могу понять, как на самом деле правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласных звуков в русском языке в зависимости от метода подсчёта от 35 до 38. Спорными звуками являются [j], так как не все считают его согласным, а также [ж:'] и [ɣ], так как они встречаются лишь в ограниченном количестве слов и имеют тенденцию к исчезновению.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Можно поинтересоваться вашим личным мнением на этот счет?